# Unable to install packages from raspbian repo

Tags: software-installation, apt, raspbian

I am unable to install certain packages on raspbian.
On trying to install ristretto, links2, pqiv, fim packages i get the following error "Unable to detect package"

```
$ sudo apt-get install ristretto 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: unable to locate package ristretto

$ sudo apt-get install links2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: unable to locate package links2

$ sudo apt-get install fim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: unable to locate package fim
```

On trying to install fbi, i get the following error

[image]

Already tried the sudo apt-get update command.

Have been stuck now. These packages should have been in the raspbian repo.

Unable to figure what might have happened to cause this issue!

Comment: Please show us the relevant errors. The one you are showing is just because there is no package called `fbi`. Your question seems to be about getting a "Unable to detect package" error when installing ristretto, links2, pqiv, fim. What errors do those produce? We need the exact error message. Also, please don't post images of your terminal, just paste the text directly into your question. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting your posts.

Comment: @terdon The issue is that *there is* a package called `fbi` in the raspbian repo -- or at least, there is for most of us (including me).  I told Archit to ask about this here since it requires someone who understands `apt` well enough to explain *why* it might do this, e.g. that perhaps something is configured wrong.  I don't think these are the kind of errors it spits when there is no inet access, although that might be the problem.  We need some expertise and experience applied!

Comment: @goldilocks I guessed as much but since the error shown was not the error described, I asked for clarifications. I am guessing this is a problem with a missing repository but can't know without seeing the `sources.list`.

Comment: @terdon Okay so we are getting somewhere ;) I notice there is even a `man sources.list`.  For reference, my raspbian `/etc/apt/sources.list` has one line: `deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi`.  I thought "non-free" might have been my addition, but looking at an unadulterated copy of the last (9-9-14) raspbian image, it's the same there.

Comment: @goldilocks I took a look at my raspbian '/etc/apt/sources.list' and it has this one line: `deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy main`

I replaced it with the line in your file and still gives the same error.

Comment: @Archit ah, that's strange. Please [edit] your question and add the contents of your `sources.list`. Also, make sure you run `sudo apt-get update` _after_ adding the line that goldilocks mentioned but _before_ running the `apt-get install` commands.

Comment: The content of all the sources.list can be found with `cat /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @goldilocks, @terdon : That seemed to have been the error.

As suggested, I took a look at my raspbian `/etc/apt/sources.list` and it had this one line: 
`deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy main`

I replaced it with the line
`deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi`

Ran `sudo-apt get update`and all packages now load fine.